# Is it worth getting a master if I am not enjoying it

Tags: career-path

After getting rejected by all of my applications for master and Phd, I am now doing a theoretical physics master in my home country. Reason why I hate it;

- Most of the courses are the same as in undergraduate level. And the quality of the courses aren't good either.
- Half of the professors aren't doing research anymore.
- I even got a fail in my quantum mechanic course, which is nonsense because the lecturer did not grade my exercises for the reason that they were not worth grading. This will make me spend an extra semester for this 2 years master.
- I have just had a summer internship at Cern and am now continue to work on another project after returning home. So I am now running low on time to do anything.
- Half of the time wasted to unrelated courses.
- I am broke, course fee is an issues and currently relying on my family.

Reason why to:

- My supervisor is really really supportive, and he says that a master degree will make it easier for me to get a PhD?. I want to work on my thesis with him. I really enjoy the project.
- I enjoy studying with my friends, which are also hating on the department.
- My mom keep getting worried if I don't make any money or not keep on study.
- I don't have any other choice but to do this master, it help to guarentee my science career??
- There is NO opportunity to do science in my country without a PhD.
- There is NO opportunity to do a PhD in particle physics in my country.

My question is: Is it worth getting this master degree. If I were to continue to do this master, is it worth spending substaintial amount of time to get good grades(For PhD applications).

You might say: If you don't enjoy it, then don't do it. But I am affraid that I might make a great mistake in my career path.
I am not that an extra ordinary student, just someone who is curious and want to learn while can earn enough to sustain my self and my needs. All of the scholarships' requirements make me feel uneased

Comment: "he says that a master degree will make it easier for me to get a PhD"  Have any students from your program gotten PhDs?  If so, ask them about this.

Comment: What exactly is your goal?

Comment: To me, describing yourself as “just someone who is curious and want to learn” would suggest that the piece of paper (the diploma, the degree) is unimportant. And if you’re not enjoying or learning from the program, then why continue?  But these are questions that only you can answer. Nobody else’s answer **can** be right for you.

Comment: There are plenty of PhDs that require a master degree. Maybe it is easier in the sense of having more chances (statistically speaking).

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are stuck in a shitty department. And that's not unusual. Plenty of shitty departments out there in this world. Not your fault.

> I am not that an extra ordinary student, just someone who is curious and want to learn while can earn enough to sustain my self and my needs.

In my book, that puts you above 80% of the PhD students I know. Most graduate students will have an elevator speech of why they are pursuing the PhD, something that sounds laudable and good to academics' ears. But most are in fact doing PhDs because they didn't know what else to do with their lives, so decided to extend their undergrad in a graduate program.

Wanting to learn, fulfill your curiosity, and to make a living are all 100% legitimate reasons for going on to graduate school and getting a PhD. Some academics talk about graduate school like it's preparation for the monastery. It's just a job. A job that can be nice to have, but still a job.

Based on the description of your country's resources for students of Physics, it seems that you will have to emigrate to a country that does have the resources. Are you willing to do that? If you are, then evaluate finishing the master's in the context of if this will help you emigrate. I can't tell you if getting a master's will help you emigrate, because it depends on your country and the country you want to move to, your citizenship status, etc.

Comment: What I need is just grants, funding. I can move when ever I wish if I had the financial capability. Thanks for your comment!